# Executing sub-transformation in a Pentaho Job executed using Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pentaho

I am trying to execute a Pentaho job and transformation using Springboot and I have been able to execute both of them successfully. But, the problem that arises is when I try to execute a Pentaho job that has transformations linked within it that I have connected using the `${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}` parameter. It works successfully in the Pentaho PDI but when I am trying to execute it using my Springboot code, I am faced with the following error:

```
2022/10/10 10:51:04 - data-fetch - Starting entry [Check S3 DB Connections]
2022-10-10T10:51:04.632+0530
      (org.pentaho.di.job.Job) [http-nio-8085-exec-10] INFO   - [src/main/resources/pentaho/data-fetch.kjb]  Starting entry [Check S3 DB Connections]
2022/10/10 10:51:14 - data-fetch - Starting entry [S3-Transformation]
2022-10-10T10:51:14.828+0530
      (org.pentaho.di.job.Job) [http-nio-8085-exec-10] INFO   - [src/main/resources/pentaho/data-fetch.kjb]  Starting entry [S3-Transformation]
2022/10/10 10:51:14 - S3-Transformation - ERROR (version 9.0.0.1-497, build 9.0.0.1-497 from 2020-03-19 08.25.00 by buildguy) : Unable to run job data-fetch. The S3-Transformation has an error. The transformation path ${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}/S3-fetch.ktr is invalid, and will not run successfully.
2022/10/10 10:51:14 - S3-Transformation - ERROR (version 9.0.0.1-497, build 9.0.0.1-497 from 2020-03-19 08.25.00 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
2022/10/10 10:51:14 - S3-Transformation - The transformation path ${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}/S3-fetch.ktr is invalid, and will not run successfully.
```

Is there a different parameter that I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Pentaho doesn't provide the ability to automatically enable runtime variables and we need to explicitly provide them during execution. I added the following line of code to add it and it got executed successfully.

```
job.setVariable("Internal.Job.Filename.Directory", pentahoDir);​
```

Where `pentahoDir` is the variable the points to the absolute path of the directory and needs to be set up by the user.